# How to access SQLite database via Isolated Storage?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I try to access to my new SQLite database via `IsolatedStorage` but when I do:

```
new SQLiteConnection(_dbpath);
```

The database is not found.
Here is my code to create file:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (!isoStore.FileExists("TestDB.sqlite"))
{
    isoStore.CreateFile("TestDB.sqlite");
}
_dbpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "SportInDB.sqlite");
```

Did I miss anything while creating a new SQLiteConnection?

Answer (score 0):

How about a minimal example?  It creates a database with a table that matches the `class Question`.

---

```
// namespaces
using SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// define a class like table to create
public class Question
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
} 

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string dbPath = "";

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // combine the local folder with the file name of the database
        dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");                        

        CreateDBTable();            
    }

    // from the MSDN article for getting SQLite to work
    private async Task<bool> FileExists(string fileName)
    {
        var result = false;
        try
        {
            var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return result;
    }

    // if the file doesn't exist, create it with the db.CreateTable
    public void CreateDBTable()
    {
        if (!FileExists("db.sqlite").Result)
        {
            using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
            {
                db.CreateTable<Question>();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i work with silverlight app and i don't have Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path

Comment: when i do the new connection path is not found...but getfileasync return the good value..

Comment: If you don't have `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` in your 8.0 WP Silverlight or 8.1 WP Silverlight then you have a huge problem.  You need to fix that first.  Create a blank silver light app from the template, can you access it in there or does it have red lines under the text?

Comment: Yeah yeah it's ok for that but i have the same problem.